# Can a teenager be company for a 9 y/o so that neither are 'unaccompanied minors'?

Tags: air-travel, minors, alaska-airlines

Two children traveling on a direct flight with family on each end.  Per the airline rules (Alaska Airlines), for a teenager, traveling as a designated 'unaccompanied minor' is optional.  Can a teenager be the  "company" for an 9 y/o so that neither are "unaccompanied minors"?

Comment: How old is the teenager? If the teenager flying alone would be an unaccompanied minor, then obviously two unaccompanied minors can't accompany each other. "Unaccompanied" means "not with an adult", not "alone".

Comment: Short for "years old".

Comment: @KjeldSchmidt: right, but the title says 9 and the question body says 8, so which age is it really?

Comment: Heh, interesting way to cheat around the wording ;) It's short for "not accompanied by a non-minor" though; you can't just put two or more minors together.

Comment: @PeterCordes, whoops, misread your question. My bad.

Comment: This kind of questions is exactly the reason why laws are written with such elaborately verbose wordings, also known as legalese. The intent of the law should have been pretty clear, so you probably already know the answer. Why even bother sending in the poor teenager? Surely the 8/9 \m/ would be accompanied by other people on the airline, which makes the whole law a farce, don't you think?

Comment: The problem is not the ends, it's the travel. What happens if your kid has an accident in the terminal, or in the middle of the flight (from benign to life-threatening)?  How will their sibling feel if the kid dies, or loses a limb (down to a finger tip), etc... will the guilt follow them all their life? What happens if the plane is rerouted to another airport and it takes 2 days instead to convey them to destination?

Comment: Why would you "not want them to be" U.M.'s ???  Doesn't make much sense?

Comment: Does that airline charge a fee for UM ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed. This is not the Cambridge college where you can only walk on the lawn if you're accompanied by a Fellow, and nobody's quite sure if a Fellow can walk on the lawn alone.

Comment: @Fattie  UM policies have the kids under very tight control.  They're designed around kids at the youngest end of the range; an older teen would likely find them obnoxiously oppressive.

Comment: Thanks all!  @Matthieu I completely agree.  As I think you guessed, the goal here was to settle a query posed by our rule-questioning teen, not by the parents.  Separately, halfway through writing I realized the 9th birthday would have passed by the travel date.

Comment: hi @DanNeely, hmm, FYI that's not been my experience.  OP - ah, you were just wondering hypothetically.  Cool.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to Alaska's [policy](https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/policies/children-traveling-alone/unaccompanied-minor-booking):

> Unaccompanied minor service is required for all children, ages 5
>   through 12 years old, traveling without a parent, legal guardian, or
>   other adult at least 18 years of age.

So this would only be possible if the teenager was 18 or over.